# How to get desired multidimensional array with dynamic form?

Tags: php, html

I want to get desired multidimensional array as follows:

```
array (
  array (abc => 'a', def => 1),
  array (abc => 'b',def => 2)
)
```

But unable to get idea how to build its form. Help me on this guys.

I tried to build form as follows with expectation to get the above results.

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<textarea name="test[][abc]"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="test[][def]">
<textarea name="test[][abc]"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="test[][def]">
// the 2nd set of textarea and input was dynamically generated by jQuery
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Apologize if earlier questions not completed for you guys to understand.

UPDATED :

After certain modification on HTML I successfully get an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [scope] => Array
        (
            [0] => iusd
            [1] => aishsadf
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 723186
            [1] => 324
        )

)
```

How to access the value and pair it?

Comment: show your html form

Comment: this is such a vague question

Comment: If you don't want this post closed, you better add some relevant information.

Comment: @melkawakibi he asked using dynamic form

Comment: they way you grouping data is wrong @azrull

Comment: you array should be something like this Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [scope] => iusd
            [qry] => 723186
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [scope] => aishsadf
            [qty] => 324
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify same index(key) for both texteara and textbox pair unless each data push into new index like this

```
array (
       array (abc => 'a'),
       array (def => 1),
       array (abc => 'b'),
       array (def => 2)
      )
```

So form should be like this

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
 <textarea name="test[0][abc]"></textarea>
 <input type="text" name="test[0][def]">
 <textarea name="test[1][abc]"></textarea>
 <input type="text" name="test[1][def]">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

OUTPUT

```
`array (
          array (abc => 'a', def => 1),
          array (abc => 'b',def => 2)
      )`
```

Answer (score 0):

Gather the values in an multidimensional array by giving the input fields a name with [][]. Let the post request post to the same file for testing purposes. Print the values out by creating a nested foreach statement.

```
//filename = post.php
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <label>field1</label>
    <input type="text" name="array[0][value1]">
    <label>field2</label>
    <input type="text" name="array[1][value2]">

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

 <?php

    if(isset($_POST)){
      $array = $_POST['array'];

      foreach($array as $key => $array2){
         foreach($array2 as $key => $value){
            echo $value;
         }       
      }
    }
?>
```